# Can't make it for outbound flight to UK, but I can make it for return flight from Europe. Will return flight be voided?

Tags: visas, air-travel, standard-visitor-visas, qatar-airways, missed-flights

So I've recently heard that if I didn't show up for the outbound leg of my journey, the return leg will be voided, and thus I can't use it to get back home. Is this true? I'm taking Qatar Airways by the way.

I am afraid that this will happen to me, as I've yet to receive any updates on my UK Visa, and my outbound flight is to Manchester, while my return flight is from Paris, which I've already gotten a Valid Schengen Visa. My flight is in less than a month, and the UK Visa will take 15 days to process, so I doubt there will be enough time to reapply for one again before the flight.

My initial plan if that my current UK Visa application is rejected again, I would buy a one-way ticket to Europe, and then return using the return leg of the original ticket that I've already booked.

Just want to know if anyone have ever faced something like this before, or was caught in a similar situation as me. If you did, I would really love to know how did you overcome it, is it buying a new ticket to Europe all together, or are you able to still use the return leg of the original ticket and just buy a one-way ticket to Europe.

Comment: You will not be allowed to use the return leg of a flight whose outbound leg you didn't fly. It's a basic rule in airline ticket pricing. Your best solution if you cannot get the UK visa in time or at all is to cancel the ticket. Most airlines even though they will not give you the money back, will hold it for one year if you want to reschedule. The problem is they usually won't allow you to use it for a different route, only the same route however there is little harm in trying.

Answer (score 4):

If you just no-show then you will lose all remaining flights on the ticket.

If you know you will not be able to take the flight your best bet is to get in touch with the airline and/or your travel agent and try to change your ticket to a different flight. There will likely be a fee for this but it will almost certainly be cheaper than starting from scratch.